# o How to use a loop structure to subset a dataframe for each unique date and apply filters for each unique point in time

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, filter, subset

I am new to R and would appreciate any help with this project.
I have a dataframe that contains data for multiple dates (31/8/2022 and 31/5/2022).

[sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf5sN.png)

I am looking to use a loop structure to subset the dataframe for each unique date, and apply multiple filters for each subset of data.

I tried creating a vector of unique dates and called it "evaluation_dates". Then tried to create a loop structure to apply a filter micbb == "XNYS" and return top 2 by ff_mktcap for each unique date subset.

Lastly I want to combine the results of each filter for each unique date, and call the dataframe "combined_screens".

Below is the code that I tried to no avail.

```
#Vector of unique dates in df
evaluation_dates <- unique(df$marketdate)                 

a <- list(evaluation_dates)

for(i in 1:length(evaluation_dates)){

filter(df, micbb == "XNYS")
top_n(df, 2, ff_mktcap)

a[[i]] <-
}  
  combined_screens <- do.call(rbind,a)
```

Ultimately the combined screens output should return :-

[Combined screen output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hosN.png)

Comment: Weclome to stack overflow.  Generally speaking it's better to paste data in using `dput(head( [your data frame]))` instead of a screenshot - people using screen readers won't be able to see your data, and we can't copy paste it to test things.

Comment: Generally though, this is a good use case for either `dplyr` or the `Data Table` packge.  I prefer the `dplyr` style which would be `group_by(marketdate) |> filter(micbb == "XNYS") |> slice_max(ff_mktcap, n=2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Making test data:

```
testdf <- data.frame(marketdate = rep(c("31/8/2022","31/5/2022"), each = 5),
                     sedol = letters[1:10],
                     isin = LETTERS[1:10],
                     tickerbb = letters[11:20],
                     micbb = c("OOTC",
                               rep("XNYS",3),
                               rep("XNGS",2),
                               rep("XNYS",2),
                               "OOTC",
                               "XNYS"),
                     ff_mktcap = runif(10,3700,12000))
```

### Performing grouping, filtering, slicing:

```
library(dplyr)

testdf |>
  group_by(marketdate) |>
  filter(micbb == "XNYS") |>
  slice_max(ff_mktcap, n=2) |>
  ungroup()
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  marketdate sedol isin  tickerbb micbb ff_mktcap
  <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>
1 31/5/2022  h     H     r        XNYS      8768.
2 31/5/2022  g     G     q        XNYS      7531.
3 31/8/2022  d     D     n        XNYS      8820.
4 31/8/2022  c     C     m        XNYS      8714.
```

Comment: @Richard glad to hear it - if it sorts your issue could you please tick the "accepted" button next to the answer?